# Which GridView in mvc should I use?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am really confused about `GridView` available in ASP.NET MVC via `nuget package` can you please provide me help regarding it? I am having the requirement of paging, searching and sorting along with the `CheckBox` as header any advice and suggestion are warmly welcome.

Answer (score 0):

There are some jQuery grid's that supports your need, you just need to implement server side sorting, paging and filtering. These are some is valuable to try:

1. jQGrid
2. jqxGrid that is commercial but has good capabilities
3. EasyUi grid is also commercial
4. ng-grid: still does not support all you need, but is based on Angularjs which I love

Answer (score 0):

Datatables.net is one of the best jQuery based smart table components out there.
And there is a Razor helper to use it in asp.mvc: [Mvc.JQuery.Datatables](https://github.com/mcintyre321/mvc.jquery.datatables)

You can get it through Nuget by doing:

```
Install-Package Mvc.JQuery.Datatables
```

Answer (score 0):

The important thing to realize is you do not need an ASP.NET MVC solution.  Any javascript solution is available to you.  It depends on how you are delivering your data.  Are you feeding up JSON via AJAX or are you using an MVC ViewModel.  My recommendation is to use AJAX and then your options are less limited. I like Wijmo especially the new version 5 which is in beta and fully supports Angular.  Kendo is pretty good but I've had a few issues with it.

Comment: Hi @Trevor im not using JSON i was just using the Model to Bind grid i need to know how this could be done with json via ajax im a beginner to the asp .net mvc any help would be considered Please let me know what is easy for me .i need search sort and paging with url maintainence wijmo as far as i know it is paid any opensource control u can show me

Comment: My preference is to use Ajax.  If you're not then consider either the MVC wrappers to Kendo UI (not free): http://www.telerik.com/campaigns/aspnet-mvc/free-trial-1?gclid=CL2znfWuisECFUVo7AodfGYAZQ 

or one of the MVC grids on codeplex:  http://gridmvc.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

down load jqgrid and use this one http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html, it is easy to implement it.

Comment: excuse me go to menu-> advanced ->multi select

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest `Kendo GridView`. They are having lot of features like, sorting paging, searching, column hide/show etc.

Comment: That is, if you want to spend a lot of money

Comment: @user3153169, you are wrong. There's a free `Kendo UI Web`

Comment: Kendo Grid is available only in Kendo UI Professional which is not free